# saving new product problem in magento 1.8.1

Tags: php, database, ce-1.8.1.0, html, zend-framework

i get this error when im saving a new product:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:139:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '484-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'";i:1;s:3403:"#0 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('cataloginventor...', Array)
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item))
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->saveInventoryData(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer), 'saveInventoryDa...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(549): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#14 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->_afterSave()
#15 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/community/Manu/Saleproducts/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(330): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#16 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/community/Manu/Saleproducts/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(238): Manu_Saleproducts_Catalog_ProductController->_autosale_add_category(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), '86')
#17 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/community/Manu/Saleproducts/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(180): Manu_Saleproducts_Catalog_ProductController->autoSaleCategory(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#18 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Manu_Saleproducts_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#19 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#20 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /home/mysite/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}";s:3:"url";s:93:"/index.php/moh3n/catalog_product/save/set/4/type/simple/key/015d93a4004a1a37e257bf575762e5e9/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: try disabling the `Manu_Saleproducts` extension. Or contact the developer for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of any custom extension used. You will need to comment all extensions one by one, clear cache and then check.